# Issue with Foundation JavaScript when loading from CDN

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to have a dropdown menu on my site. I got it working fine when storing the files on my server. However, I'd like to load them from a CDN. What happens when I try this though is that the CSS aspects work fine, but the JavaScript aspects don't, which means that the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="top-bar-right">
                <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dropdown menu</a>
                        <ul class="menu vertical">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">First dropdown link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Second dropdown link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

just produces this:

[image: The result]

Any ideas what's wrong with this code?

Comment: What does your debugger say?  Press F12.

Comment: @zero298 Hm, it says `Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function` referring to `jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4`...

Answer (score 0):

A quick check at https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/v6.3/bower.json shows that Foundation 6 supports jquery version ~ 2.2.0 so changing your JQuery version should solve your issue

```js
$(document).foundation();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.js"></script>


<div class="top-bar">
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Dropdown menu</a>
        <ul class="menu vertical">
          <li>
            <a href="#">First dropdown link</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Second dropdown link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```